# Update table column using transformation rule in Oracle APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex

I am a beginner to  Oracle APEX 5 and need your help in transformation rule creation.Below is the problem scenario:

I have an csv sheet (test.csv) which contains 3 fields , let say c1 , c2 and c3  with 100 records which I need to upload to Oracle table. I have a table MYTAB   in Oracle database  which  contains 4 columns let say c1,c2,c3 and c4.The fields c1,c2 and c3 from csv are mapped to the columns c1,c2 and c3 of database table MYTAB. I have created a data upload page where I am able to upload the csv data to Oracle table.Now during the csv upload , I want to create a transformation rule such that during the csv upload , the column c4 of table MYTAB shall be updated with a specific value of field c1 which is there in csv.

```
test.csv

c1     c2      c3

101    xx       aa

102    yy       bb

103    zz       kk

104    mm       yy
```

Expected result in Oracle table after csv upload

```
 Mytab

c1     c2      c3     c4

101   xx      aa    101

102   yy      bb    101

103   zz     kk     101

104   mm     yy     101
```

Could you please suggest how this can be  done? What syntax needs to be followed here? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

actually i dont know how to do in apex but you may create a trigger for new record insert action on table as below and populate C4 with a simple select query in existing data

create or replace trigger "MYTABLE_TRIGGERNAME"
  before insert on "MYTABLE"
  for each row
begin
  if :NEW."C4" is null then 
    select C1 into :NEW."C4" from MYTABLE where C1=....; 
  end if; 
end; 
​